# 'const' values in array dimensions

Tags: c, constants

The below code snippet works and compiles in C:

```
const int n=10;

int main(void)
{
    int a[n];
    return 0;
}
```

However, when the array is declared in global scope, it throws a compilation error.

```
const int n=10;
int a[n];

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't it throw an error inside *main*?

Comment: What compilation error does it throw?

Answer (score 5):

Despite `n` being marked as const, it's not a compile time constant<sup>1</sup>. As such the array `a` is a variable length array<sup>2</sup>.

VLA's cannot have static storage duration. Placing it at file scope makes it a static variable, and your program is ill-formed because of it<sup>3</sup>.

---

1. [C11 N1570/6.6p6](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p6)

   > An integer constant expression117) shall have integer type and **shall only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, sizeof expressions whose results are integer constants, _Alignof expressions, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts.** Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an operand to the sizeof or _Alignof operator.
2. [C11 N1570/6.7.6.2p4](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p4)

   > If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type. If the size is * instead of being an expression, the array type is a variable length array type of unspecified size, which can only be used in declarations or type names with function prototype scope;143) such arrays are nonetheless complete types. **If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type; otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type**.
3. [C11 N1570/6.7.6.2p2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p2)

   > If an identifier is declared as having a variably modified type, it shall be an ordinary identifier (as defined in 6.2.3), have no linkage, and have either block scope or function prototype scope. **If an identifier is declared to be an object with static or thread storage duration, it shall not have a variable length array type.**

Comment: I think, it should be noted that VLA's do not need to be allocated on the stack, they can be allocated on the heap as well: `int (*array)[foo] = malloc(sizeof(*array));`. The restriction is an explicit restriction to deal with the fact that there is no defined execution order of global/thread storage declaration statements in C. Consequently, there is no notion of "this variable has that value at this VLA declaring statement" for globals.

Comment: @cmaster - The C standard makes no mention of stack or heap, and nor did I. I was very careful to stick with the wording of the standard, that speaks in terms of storage duration.

Comment: @cmaster that is a (dynamically) allocated array being pointed to by a pointer of variably modified type. The term "VLA" refers to automatic arrays

Comment: @M.M That is a very narrow interpretation of the term "VLA". Afaik, the C standard does not primarily talk about VLAs in that narrow sense (apart from specific exemptions like the ones cited in this answer), rather it defines what a "variable length array type" is, and allows them to be used pretty much anywhere in executable code. Your specific meaning of VLA is just a specific consequence of a much broader concept.

Comment: To put it another way, you could say that all malloc'd space is arrays with runtime length.